# Insert div in other div location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div "div.share-tools" which I want inside "div.single-column div.middle" I am using "append" to do this. but its not working.

I need help in this.

```js
j$(document).ready(function() { j$('div.single-column div.middle').append('div.share-tools'); });
```

```css
.share-tools {
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 position: relative;
 top: 7px;
 left: 830px;
 text-align: center;
}
.form-page .share-tools {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
   <div class="share-tools">
  <p><strong>Follow Bar</strong>
  </p>
  <span class="st_facebook_custom" st_processed="yes"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/FIPPmagazines"><img onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Facebook', 'ArticleShare',  'Middle East focus: Evolving editorial for a growing market')" alt="" src="https://custom.cvent.com/87E7E574200F45ABB2697C8CB2E584DC/pix/8756b08d940b444ba9d069a53936ae71.png"></a></span> 
  <span
  st_via="FIPPWorld" class="st_twitter_custom" st_processed="yes">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Middle%20East%20focus%3A%20Evolving%20editorial%20for%20a%20growing%20market&source=sharethiscom&related=sharethis&via=FIPPWorld&url=http://fipp.com/news/features/middle-east-focus-james-hewes#sthash.dx3fgoZo.uxfs">
      <img onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Twitter', 'ArticleShare', 'Middle East focus: Evolving editorial for a growing market')" alt="" src="https://custom.cvent.com/87E7E574200F45ABB2697C8CB2E584DC/pix/54596e96875044318f6a6bcbb4fde4be.png">
    </a>
    </span> <span class="st_facebook_custom" st_processed="yes"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsharer%2Fsharer.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ffipp.com%252Fnews%252Ffeatures%252Fmiddle-east-focus-james-hewes%26ret%3Dlogin&display=popup#sthash.dx3fgoZo.gbpl&t=Middle%20East%20focus%3A%20Evolving%20editorial%20for%20a%20growing%20market"><img onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Facebook', 'ArticleShare',  'Middle East focus: Evolving editorial for a growing market')" alt="" src="https://custom.cvent.com/87E7E574200F45ABB2697C8CB2E584DC/pix/d01f0a803ded492097d8c21a7bd0cb0e.png"></a></span> 
    <span
    displaytext="LinkedIn" class="st_linkedin_custom" st_processed="yes">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2FpostLogin%3Fsession_rikey%3DoIQlgRWQjbUR1XC6Rj7g3fkHJfBz4LiPftHLQjaFY8b4VvsaI3Dk5jBausr4PNRzPjiLqp_H0zUPz1Mc3Tewv34SajutVuIf2Kh%26l%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww%252Elinkedin%252Ecom%252FshareArticle%253Fmini%253Dtrue%2526url%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Ffipp%25252Ecom%25252Fnews%25252Ffeatures%25252Fmiddle-east-focus-james-hewes%25253Fsthash%25252Edx3fgoZo%25252Emjjo%2526source%253D%2526title%253DMiddle%252BEast%252Bfocus%25253A%252BEvolving%252Beditorial%252Bfor%252Ba%252Bgrowing%252Bmarket%2526summary%253DConsumer%252Bpublishing%252Bin%252Bthe%252BMiddle%252BEast%252Bis%252Bon%252Bthe%252Bup%25252E%252BThe%252BUAEs%252Bcontinues%252Bto%252Blead%252Bthe%252Bregion%2525E2%252580%252599s%252Bmedia%252Bscene%25252E%252BWith%252Ba%252Bmedian%252Bage%252Bof%252Bjust%252B30%252Band%252Ban%252Binternet%252Bpenetration%252Brate%252Bof%252B96%252Bper%252Bcent%252Bof%252Bthe%252Boverall%252Bpopulation%25252C%252Bit%2525E2%252580%252599s%252Bno%252Bsurprise%252Bthat%252Bmuch%252Bof%252Bthe%252Bgrowth%252Bin%252Bmagazine%252Bmedia%252Bin%252Bthe%252BUAE%252Bis%252Btaking%252Bplace%252Bonline%25252E%26id%3D0%26b%3D95999708-0136-417e-83c6-48cb7d2e6826%26h%3DeeQp%26m%3DGET">
        <img onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'LinkedIn','ArticleShare',  'Middle East focus: Evolving editorial for a growing market')" alt="" src="https://custom.cvent.com/87E7E574200F45ABB2697C8CB2E584DC/pix/0e01af7e76e3461e9c6d38361580d0ef.png">
      </a>
      </span> <span displaytext="Google +" class="st_googleplus_custom" st_processed="yes"><a target="_blank" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=oz&passive=1209600&continue=https://plus.google.com/share?url%3Dhttp://fipp.com/news/features/middle-east-focus-james-hewes%2523sthash.8wcUbxKy.hpvt%26hl%3Den-US%26gpsrc%3Dframeless&btmpl=popup&hl=en-US#identifier"><img onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'GPlus', 'ArticleShare', 'Middle East focus: Evolving editorial for a growing market')" alt="" src="https://custom.cvent.com/87E7E574200F45ABB2697C8CB2E584DC/pix/eefab194c0204b56834abefa73cbf677.png"></a></span> 
      <span
      displaytext="Google +" class="st_googleplus_custom" st_processed="yes">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://instagram.com/FIPPworld">
          <img onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'GPlus', 'ArticleShare', 'Middle East focus: Evolving editorial for a growing market')" alt="" src="https://custom.cvent.com/87E7E574200F45ABB2697C8CB2E584DC/pix/2bc43366f1744a29a26652b2ff4b298a.png">
        </a>
        </span> <span displaytext="Google +" class="st_googleplus_custom" st_processed="yes"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.pinterest.com/FIPPWorld/"><img onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'GPlus', 'ArticleShare', 'Middle East focus: Evolving editorial for a growing market')" alt="" src="https://custom.cvent.com/87E7E574200F45ABB2697C8CB2E584DC/pix/fea31ed44c944e8fbaaf5ec2c2114687.png"></a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the jquery library and I am not 100% on this but I have not seen a variable before the $ symbol as you have done with the letter 'j'.

Comment: I have included jquery and j$ is mentioned in no conflict

Comment: @IfTrue this can be done with `var j$ = jQuery; or var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: it looks like you have some errors in your html. Can you please give us a non-minified version?

Comment: @Jai 41 - ahh interesting - thanks :) You learn something new everyday.

Comment: `"div.single-column div.middle"` where is this element?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's append expects an element, not a selector.

```
<script> j$(document).ready(function() { j$('div.single-column div.middle').append(j$('div.share-tools')); }); </script>
```

Comment: slight mistake, if you could correct it it will be the answer.